# Discord.js embed api say undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
name: "check",
category: "extra",
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const baseUrl = "https://sheetdb.io/api";

    let url, response, buyyer;

    try {
        url = args[0] ? `${baseUrl}/v1/r46h2i09etkew/search?name=${args[0]}`:`${baseUrl}/v1/r46h2i09etkew/search?name=${args[0]}`
        response = await axios.get(url)
        buyyer = response.data
    } catch (error) {
        return message.channel.send(`***${args[0]}*** doesn't exist, or data isn't being collected`)
    }
    
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(args[0] ? `Buy ${args[0].toUpperCase()}` : `buy ${args[0].toUpperCase()}`)
        .setColor('#fb644c')
        .addFields(
            {
                name: 'name:',
                value: buyyer.name,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Date:',
                value: buyyer.Date,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: 'money:',
                value: buyyer.money,
                inline: true
            })

    await message.channel.send(embed)
 }
};
```

in API link
`[{"name":"best","Date":"10\/5\/2021","money":"2400"}]`

Comment: Do you receive an array with an object? Use `buyyer = Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data[0] : response.data` to get the first item if the response is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying `response.data` returns `[{"name":"best","Date":"10\/5\/2021","money":"2400"}]`.
So `response.data` is an `Array` not an `Object`
And you're doing `buyyer = response.data`
In that case you should change the code like this

```js
.addFields({
    name: 'name:',
    value: buyyer[0].name, //First element of the response.data
    inline: true
},{
    name: 'Date:',
    value: buyyer[0].Date,
    inline: true
},{
    name: 'money:',
    value: buyyer[0].money,
    inline: true
})
```

This should do. Comment if still any error